# Order of execution of observers in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

**Goal and Current Approach**

I have a module, which can delete its own UI. I also want to be able to call this killing functionality from outside the module, hence I pass an additional reactive to the module's server logic and call the killing routine when this reactive fires.

So far so good. Now I want to implement a function which first kills all instances of my module and then adds new instances of this module and this is where I struggle with the design I have chosen.

**Issue**

What I would need is that before my `input$add5` observer adds any new instances, all old instances are killed. This would be done by setting `kill_switch(TRUE)`, but the problem is that before the `observer` in my module can react to that, the `input$add5` observer continues to add new modules, which reset the `kill_switch` to `FALSE` and basically the old instances are never killed.

Basically, in the current design I would like that the `observer` on `kill_switch` reacts immediately after I change the flag and only after this is done, my `add5` observer continues.

**What I need**

I think that my design is not optimal, thus any recommendations of how to set up the interface between the main application and the module would be highly appreciated.

---

**Code**

```
library(shiny)

boxer_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  div(
    id,
    id = ns("killme"), 
    style = "background-color:steelblue; font-size: xx-large; color: white")
}

boxer <- function(input, output, session, kill_switch) {
  ns <- session$ns
  observe({
    req(kill_switch())
    removeUI(paste0("#", ns("killme")))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("new", "new"), 
                actionButton("killall", "Kill All"), 
                actionButton("add5", "Kill All & Add 5"),
                fluidRow(id = "content"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ids <- reactiveVal(0)
  kill_switch <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  handler <- reactiveValues()

  add_new <- function() {
    kill_switch(FALSE)
    ids(ids() + 1)
    new_id <- paste0("id", ids())
    insertUI("#content", "beforeEnd", boxer_ui(new_id))
    handler[[new_id]] <- callModule(boxer, new_id, kill_switch)
  }

  observeEvent(input$new, {
    isolate({
      add_new()
    })})

  observeEvent(input$add5, {
    isolate({
      kill_switch(TRUE)
      replicate(5, add_new())
    })})

  observeEvent(input$killall, kill_switch(TRUE))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: have you already looked into the `priority` parameter of the `observe()` and `observeEvent()` function?

Comment: Yes I have seen `priority`. Would they help here? I think I have difficulties to understand how reactivity works in this case. My intuition is that `input$add5` finishes and only after it has finished, the `observer` on `kill_switch` can react. In this case I cannot see, how `priority` would help. If things work somehow in parallel and via `priority` I can tell the `kill_switch observer` to intervene then I guess that this would be a viable solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I could think of is to split `remove` / `add` as follows:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ids <- reactiveVal(0)
  kill_switch <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  add5 <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

  handler <- reactiveValues()

  add_new <- function() {
    kill_switch(FALSE)
    ids(ids() + 1)
    new_id <- paste0("id", ids())
    insertUI("#content", "beforeEnd", boxer_ui(new_id))
    handler[[new_id]] <- callModule(boxer, new_id, kill_switch)
  }

  observeEvent(input$new, {
    isolate({
      add_new()
    })})

  observeEvent(input$add5, {
    isolate({
      kill_switch(TRUE)
      add5(TRUE)
    })})

  observe({
      req(add5())
      isolate({
         replicate(5, add_new())
         add5(FALSE)
      })
  })

  observeEvent(input$killall, kill_switch(TRUE))
}
```

This is however based on the assumption that the `observer` will never be interrupted by any other `observer`. Is that true? In this case I could also add `priority` parameters to ensure that the inner `observer` is fired first.

Can anybody conform that my assumption is right?